# Flutter: Kill / Exit GestureDetector during onVerticalDragUpdate / onPanUpdate

Tags: flutter, kill-process, gesturedetector

When using GestureDetector to update the Size of a Widget, how would you exit the gesture completely once the user has reached a certain point? Is there a way to tell Flutter to stop listening to this drag gesture even whilst it is still being dragged as if the user had removed their finger from the screen.

```
GestureDetector(
  onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {
   if(details.globalPosition.dy > 100){
     // kill this gesture completely as if the user has removed their finger from the screen
}
})
```

Comment: did you try a normal return;

Comment: Why not updating variable you used for sizing widget is not just working?

Comment: Yes, however what I'm trying to do is to kill this drag gesture and allow it's child to begin scrolling.

Comment: I think what I am suggesting is working fine. I will re ask this question describing where I think the issue actually is.

Comment: Apologies, I will remove this question. I have outlined what I am trying to do in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74304197/flutter-allow-parent-and-child-to-respond-to-drag-gesture

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way, it has some pixel issue based on drag velocity(I think)

```dart
bool enabled = true;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onVerticalDragUpdate: enabled
        ? (details) {
            print(details.globalPosition.dy);
            if (details.globalPosition.dy > 100) {
              enabled = false;

              setState(() {});
              return;
            }
          }
        : null,
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It seems it was already working. The problem is in another part of my Widget and I have outlined it here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74304197/flutter-allow-parent-and-child-to-respond-to-drag-gesture